# VB.NET with pgSQL: How to change textbox type within SQL queries?

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, dotconnect

I've written a VB form on Visual Studio 2013 (.Net Framework 4.5.1) that opens and edits a pgSQL database. In order for the user to be able to search the table, I created a compobox from which the user can select the desired column to search and then enters the value he's searching for in a textbox.

In order to integrate pgSQL with VS 2013 I use Devart's software dotConnect for PostgreSQL 7.6 Express (the free edition)

This particular table has three columns (id, name, balance). In pgSQL the column type for id is *integer*, for name is *character varying* and for balance is *numeric*.

When I test the search by name everything works fine. For the other two fields, I obviously tried to change the textbox type within the SQL query by using CType and CInt, but nothing works and I get the error:

> operator does not exist: integer ~ ~ unknown

Below is my code.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    'creating pgsql connection and query
    Dim myQuery As String
    Dim pgSqlConnection1 As PgSqlConnection = New PgSqlConnection()
    pgSqlConnection1.ConnectionString = "UserId=postgres;Password=***;Host=localhost;Database=postgres;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Schema=public"

    'searches according to selected column
    If ComboBox1.Text = "customer_name" Then
        myQuery = "SELECT customer_id, customer_name, balance FROM account_current WHERE customer_name LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
        Search(myQuery, pgSqlConnection1)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "customer_id" Then
        myQuery = "SELECT customer_id, customer_name, balance FROM account_current WHERE customer_id LIKE '%" & CType(TextBox1.Text, Integer) & "%'"
        Search(myQuery, pgSqlConnection1)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "balance" Then
        myQuery = "SELECT customer_id, customer_name, balance FROM account_current WHERE balance LIKE '%" & CType(TextBox1.Text, Double) & "%'"
        Search(myQuery, pgSqlConnection1)
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub Search(myQuery As String, pgSqlConnection1 As PgSqlConnection)

    'Try statement to show error instead of crashing
    Try

        pgSqlConnection1.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim MyCommand As New PgSqlCommand(myQuery, pgSqlConnection1)
        Dim myDataAdapter As New PgSqlDataAdapter(myQuery, pgSqlConnection1)
        myDataAdapter.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        pgSqlConnection1.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me with this? 
Excuse any mischaracterizations, I'm a newbie. 
Thank's in advance!

Comment: `LIKE` doesn't work on numbers. It only works with character values. So `customer_id LIKE ...` and `balance LIKE` are wrong (and don't make much sense to me to be honest)

Answer (score 0):

Use a CAST in your query in order to be able to use the LIKE with an Integer.

Example:

```
myQuery = "SELECT customer_id, customer_name, balance FROM account_current WHERE CAST(customer_id AS TEXT) LIKE '%" & CType(TextBox1.Text, Integer) & "%'"
```

With an Integer you can also use the BETWEEN which will let you search between 2 numbers:

```
myQuery = "SELECT customer_id, customer_name, balance FROM account_current WHERE customer_id BETWEEN '%" & CType(TextBox1.Text, Integer) & "%' AND '%" & CType(TextBox1.Text, Integer) & "%'"
```

Also, if you are just starting out, take a look at npgsql which is the Postgres .NET connector: http://www.npgsql.org/